# The teams app cannot download images through js

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I currently have a problem I want to know, that is, my teams application is directly embedded in the web page, I encountered such a problem when I was developing a download QR code, in the teams environment, I can not download the QR code picture through the A tag, but in the ios system, You can open a page to display the QR code (the code is shown below). Is this issue with Android not downloadable due to teams' own security policy restrictions or other issues? Whether there is an api in the provided teams.js that can provide images to download to the local; Or can I open this QR code separately on my phone browser? If you know the solution to this problem please answer for me, I have not much time to update this feature, thank you

I tried to download the QR code image through the a TAB, but in ios system, you can open a page to display the QR code, but there is no reaction in Android, and it will trigger the download in the browser